# Extract numbers after a specific text in excel using VBA / Custom Function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a text in cell as below:

Case 1: ABC A/C# 123
Case 2 : 854ABC A/C#854

However I would like to extract numbers only after the characters "A/C".

It would be great if you guys can suggest a code with custom function, so that I can directly use the code like a default excel function.

Answer (score 2):

```
Function GetString(cell)
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "A/C#\s*(\d+)"
        With .Execute(cell)
            If .Count > 0 Then
                GetString = .Item(0).SubMatches(0)
            Else
                GetString = CVErr(xlErrNA)
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but I want to extract just the numbers after the words "A/C". For example if I have "ABC A/C# 123', I need result as just "123".